# map with failure in Numpy

Tags: python, haskell, numpy

Inspired by Haskell:

How can I implement the following with a numpy array in Python?

```
In [13]: [(x if x>3 else None) for x in range(10)]
Out[13]: [None, None, None, None, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

In other words, I am looking for a function for numpy that would have the signature: `f:[a]->(a->Maybe a)->[Maybe a]` in Haskell, where `[a]` would be a numpy list.

I was trying this:

```
np.apply_along_axis(lambda x:x if x>3 else None,0,np.arange(10))
```

but it does not work:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NumPy's [`where()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) will do the trick:

```
In [429]: import numpy as np

In [430]: arr = np.arange(10, dtype=np.object)

In [431]: np.where(arr > 3, arr, None)
Out[431]: array([None, None, None, None, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], dtype=object)
```

The code above creates a new array. If you wish to modify `arr` **in place**, you could use boolean indexing `arr[arr < 4] = None` (as pointed out by @Chris Mueller) or [`putmask()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.4/reference/generated/numpy.putmask.html):

```
In [432]: np.putmask(arr, arr < 4, None)

In [433]: arr
Out[433]: array([None, None, None, None, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], dtype=object)
```

---

Unless you are constrained to use `None` as a "flag" value, I would suggest you to stick to @ev-br's recommendation and use `np.nan` instead. I will follow that approach to assess performance:

```
In [434]: arr = np.arange(1000000, dtype=np.float)

In [435]: timeit np.where(arr > 3, arr, np.nan)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.61 ms per loop

In [436]: timeit arr[arr < 4] = np.nan
1000 loops, best of 3: 564 µs per loop

In [437]: timeit np.putmask(arr, arr < 4, np.nan)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.08 ms per loop
```

Notice that I used a much larger array to further highlight efficiency differences. And the winner is... [boolean indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays).

Answer (score 5):

I'd recommend to revisit the premise that you want `None`s in a numpy array: you need an array of `dtype=object` to store a `None`, i.e. you'll be storing python objects in an array. This way you're going to lose most of the advantages that numpy provides over plain lists.

If what you want is a sentinel value to signal "not available" or "not known", and you can have other values to be floating-point numbers, then you're better off using `np.nan`

```
>>> x = np.arange(10, dtype=float)
>>> x[x < 3] = np.nan
>>> x
array([ nan,  nan,  nan,   3.,   4.,   5.,   6.,   7.,   8.,   9.])
```

Answer (score 3):

A slightly different technique than Tonechas' which uses numpy's boolean indexing feature.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.arange(10).astype(np.object)
>>> x[x<4] = None
```

returns

```
array([None, None, None, None, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Interesting ! Thanks.